# Merged rows in column, bottom row fixed height

Tags: microsoft-word

I've been struggling some time now with a specific problem using Tables in MS Word (2010).

I have a table with 2 rows and 2 columns and the last column, the rows are merged. Now it can happen that this last cell will expand, and I would like to have the last row in the first column to be of a fixed height and the first row has to expand.

What happens now is that the last row expands and the first row has a "fixed" height. A picture of the behaviour at this moment:

[image: Table not wanted hebaviour]

And this is how I would like it to behave (the top row has to expand and the bottom row should have a fixed height):

[image: Table wanted behaviour]

I have been looking through all properties and settings, but I don't seem to find any option. Neither can I found anything by searching online (probably not using the exact right keywords).

For clarification, "hitting enter" or setting a specific height is not the way to go, as the table is dynamically filled (I don't know the content at this time, it is generated). In theory the content of the right column can be just 1 letter (the left column, both rows only have 1 line of text).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you create the table as say 12 rows by 2 columns and then merge all the cells in the RH column and also merge all but the bottom cell in the LH column.

To merge, select the relevant cells, right click and Merge.

Example added (2x2) after further comments:

[image: SU514524 example]
[image: SU514524 second example]

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, unless I really understand you wrongly. The bottom row that corresponds to the bottom row of the merged rows, will still expand. And also, the requirement is that the left bottom cell has to be aligned with the merged rows (the border has to be on the same height).

Comment: I don't know the height of the right column in advance. If I have a fixed size, I would have indeed done it your way (actually, I currently have done something simular as you suggested, but the problem is that it is a fixed size).

Comment: I am not going to work with hitting enter... It is not that I type the letter myself (it is generated, I create the "template" that has variables in it).

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the top left cell, choose **Table Properties** and then the **Row** tab. From there tick **Specify height** and choose **Exactly** from the drop down list along with the height you want the row.

The result when the table is expanded should be the first row stays the same height while the bottom row expands.

Comment: The first row should expand, not the bottom one. The bottom row has to have the fixed size.

Comment: @pnuts : tried that, it will hide the extra content in the right column. Two tables like that don't seem to be an option, unless you can demonstrate it to get the same result?

Comment: I've uploaded a test document here that I think acheives what you are looking for. Download and take a look: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4h-y94oB7DOZkQ1LTVPT2NkTEE

Comment: This solution doesn't work, because when you put more content in the right column, it will be hidden. (Again to clarify, I don't know in advance how much content the right column will contain.)

Comment: @Styxxy, Actually there is a hidden cell at the bottom of the right column. This needs to be there in order for the cell above to grow. If you insert the text into the cell above the whole column grows as expected. I'm afraid this is really the only way to achieve what you are looking for, due to row being fixed height or expandable, not both.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it is not the solution I would like. I'll have to fix it some other way.